# Is a question about Mac kernel panics from ADB on topic here?

Tags: support, scope

I'm having a strange issue with ADB, but I want to make sure this is on topic first since it's somewhat of an edge case.

When I plug my phone into my Mac, I get kernel panics on the Mac constantly and I cannot figure out why, and neither can the Apple store. It's caused by adb, which is still on topic, but of course the issue probably lies within my mac.

Would this be considered on topic? (The support tag is incorrect, I'm aware. None of the required tags work for this)

Comment: An evaluation you may want to consider beyond site scope is the concentration of knowledge that would be relevant to your question. Ask Different may simply have people who are better able to help you (but, admittedly, it's tough to say either way).

Comment: @eldarerathis that was my concern. It's an issue between 2 platforms and doesn't really fit anywhere. But as you said, Ask Different may know how to read the panic better.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried another phone (if possible try a different model rather than just another of the same make/model)?

If it doesn't cause the kernel panics i'd say the issue is likely to be with your phone so your question would be on-topic for this site.

If both devices cause the same issue then the problem is more likely to be with your Mac so my gut feeling is that it would be off-topic but it's certainly not clear-cut. We do have lots of questions about how to get adb working on PCs (using a variety of OS's) so that could suggest that it would be on-topic.

Comment: No, I never though about that, but that's something I'll certainly test this weekend

Comment: I disagree.  The OS is doing something wrong if it allows a peripheral device to trigger a kernel panic.  That said, trying to get it to work with an Android device despite this issue is probably on-topic.

Comment: The question here is not how to fix the problem, but whether fixing the problem is on-topic for the main site.